# Where does ctypes LoadLibrary() search for libs on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, ctypes

Where does `ctypes` [LoadLibrary()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries) search for a shared lib on Mac OS X?

This works:

`LoadLibrary("/full/path/to/my_library.dylib")`

However,

`LoadLibrary("my_library.dylib")`

does not work, even `/full/path/to)` is in `PATH` and in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Seems like the solution is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On *OSX* (as on (almost) any *Nix*), *CTypes* uses *dlopen* to open an *.so* (*.dylib*). According to [[Apple.Developer]: DLOPEN(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dlopen.3.html) (or *man dlopen*) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> When *path* doesn't contain a slash character (i.e. it is just a leaf name), **dlopen()** searches the following until it finds a compatible Mach-O file: ***$LD_LIBRARY_PATH***, ***$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH***, ***current working directory***, ***$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH***.

So, you could launch your script like (where ***%***s mark placeholders):

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:%PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB_DIR% %COMMAND_LAUNCHING_SCRIPT%
```