# Can't import dll module in Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes, uvc

I've been stressin for a few days trying to compile a modified version of libuvc on windows and now that I've finally done it, I can't seem to load it on Python. This lib that I've already compiled and successfully imported using the same version of Python on Linux machines, doesn't like w10 at all.

**System**

- win 10 64 bit
- python 3.8 64 bit
- libusb 1.022
- libuvc.dll compiled with MinGW64

**Problem**

When trying the

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
name = ctypes.util.find_library('libuvc')
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\libuvc\lib\libuvc.dll'.
Try using the full path with constructor syntax. 
Error: could not find libuvc!
```

The issue is that the file exists since it was found by util.find_library, but python doesn't think it is where it is, or maybe the output is just the default. What am I missing here? What could be failing to be unable to not just load the module, but find it? I'm sorry I don't have more output than this.

P.S: I've tried reformatting the string in different ways, but the message doesn't change.

Comment: Perhaps something to do with permissions on that file? Give [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) a try and see what happened while accessing that file.

Comment: what would be an error message that would indicate permission error? cause there is a lot of feed in process monitor. What am i supposed to be looking for? there is a lot of successful readings of the dll.

Comment: Filter by the path you're trying to access. Or try to count the Result column and look for some permission denied or similar

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650202/235698) for how to use Process Monitor to find a DLL issue.  It may be a dependent DLL in a different path it can't find, so limiting by path could miss something.  Limit by process and CreateFile and look at the end of the list after trying to load your DLL.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of filing a minor bug with python to resolve the discrepancy between the docs and the actual behavior: https://bugs.python.org/issue42114

Comment: Can someone tell me what Python means by "constructor syntax"?

Answer (score 26):

Starting with *Python 3.**8***, the *.dll* search mechanism has changed (***Win* specific**).

According to [[Python.Docs]: os.add_dll_directory(path)](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Add a path to the DLL search path.
>
> This search path is used when resolving dependencies **for imported extension modules** (the module itself is resolved through [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path)), **and also by [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)**.
>
> ...
>
> **[Availability](https://docs.python.org/library/intro.html#availability): Windows**.

So, you could do:

```py
os.add_dll_directory("${path_to_working_dlls_directoy}")
```

where *${path_to_working_dlls_directoy}* is a placeholder for the actual path and it (obviously) should be replaced by it.

You can check [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546) (which although it seems very different, has **the same cause**), for more details.

*P.S.*: ***Nix* *OS*es are not impacted**.

---

#### Update *#0*

While I based my answer on (official) documentation, [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@MadPhysicist's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472088/4788546) (**great answer *BTW***) came with the **why** part.
However, there are some aspects that need to be clarified.

Everything I stated about *os.add_dll_directory* is correct and still applies. According to [[MS.Learn]: LoadLibraryExA function (libloaderapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> - **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS** 
>   0x00001000
>
>   This value is ***a combination of*** **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR**, **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32**, and **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS**. Directories in the standard search path are not searched. This value cannot be combined with **LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH**. 
>   This value represents the recommended maximum number of directories an application should include in its DLL search path

> - **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS** 
>   0x00000400
>
>   If this value is used, ***directories added using the [AddDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) or the [SetDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya) function are searched*** for the DLL and its dependencies.

This is the mechanism used by default (**`winmode=None`**, as *LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS* is passed to *LoadLibraryEx*).
When setting **`winmode=0`**, *Win* default search mechanism kicks in. [[MS.Learn]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order - Standard Search Order for Desktop Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications) states (last item - regardless of *SafeDllSearchMode*, ***emphasis*** still mine):

> 6. The ***directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable***. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the **App Paths** registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

I prepared a small example.
*Python* code attempts to load (via *CTypes*) ***dll00.dll*** located in the same *dir*, which in turn is linked to (**depends on**) another one (***dll01.dll***) located in a different *dir* (***subdir00***).

- *dll00.c*:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  int dll01Func00();

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL00_EXPORT_API int dll00Func00();

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif


  int dll00Func00() {
      printf("%s - %d - %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
      dll01Func00();
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- *dll01.c*:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define DLL01_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL01_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL01_EXPORT_API int dll01Func00();

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif


  int dll01Func00() {
      printf("%s - %d - %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import argparse
  import ctypes as cts
  import os
  import sys


  DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")

  METH_ADDLLDIR = "a"
  METH_PATH = "p"
  METHS = (
      METH_ADDLLDIR,
      METH_PATH,
  )


  def parse_args(*argv):
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Python .dll search path (Win) example")
      parser.add_argument("--path", "-p", choices=METHS)
      parser.add_argument("--winmode", "-w", type=int)

      args, unk = parser.parse_known_args()
      if unk:
          print("Warning: Ignoring unknown arguments: {:}".format(unk))
      return args.path, args.winmode


  def main(*argv):
      meth, wmod = parse_args()
      print("PATH (original): {:}\n".format(os.environ.get("PATH")))
      print("Using winmode={:}".format(wmod))
      if meth is not None:
          subdir = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "subdir00")
          if meth == METH_ADDLLDIR:
              add_dll_directory = getattr(os, "add_dll_directory", None)
              if add_dll_directory:
                  os.add_dll_directory(subdir)
                  print("Using AddDllDirectory()\n")
          elif meth == METH_PATH:
              os.environ["PATH"] = os.pathsep.join((os.environ.get("PATH", ""), subdir))
              print("Using %PATH%\n")
      dll00 = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME, winmode=wmod)
      print("Dll: {:}".format(dll00))
      if False:  # No need to actually call the function
          dll00Func00 = dll00.dll00Func00
          dll00Func00.argtypes = ()
          dll00Func00.restype = cts.c_int
          res = dll00Func00()
          print("\n{0:s} returned: {1:d}".format(dll00Func00.__name__, res))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Notes**:

- There are 2 variables here (alterable via command line arguments):

  - *path* - how *subdir00* should be added to *.dll* search paths:

    1. Do nothing (don't add it)
    2. Pass it to *os.add_dll_directory*
    3. Append it to *%PATH%*
  - *winmode* - to be passed to *CDLL* initializer (only illustrating for *0* and *None*)

  As a consequence, 6 combinations emerge

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> tree /a /f
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is AE9E-72AC
> E:.
> |   code00.py
> |   dll00.c
> |   dll01.c
> |   test.bat
> |
> \---subdir00
>
> [prompt]> :: Build .dlls
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL /MD dll01.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:subdir00\dll01.dll
> dll01.c
>    Creating library subdir00\dll01.lib and object subdir00\dll01.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL /MD dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll subdir00\dll01.lib
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> tree /a /f
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is AE9E-72AC
> E:.
> |   code00.py
> |   dll00.c
> |   dll00.dll
> |   dll00.exp
> |   dll00.lib
> |   dll00.obj
> |   dll01.c
> |   dll01.obj
> |   test.bat
> |
> \---subdir00
>         dll01.dll
>         dll01.exp
>         dll01.lib
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py -h
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> usage: code00.py [-h] [--path {a,p}] [--winmode WINMODE]
>
> Python .dll search path (Win) example
>
> options:
>   -h, --help            show this help message and exit
>   --path {a,p}, -p {a,p}
>   --winmode WINMODE, -w WINMODE
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Going through combinations. When an argument is not passed, its default value is None
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> PATH (original): c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4
> .8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts;C:\Us
> ers\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools;;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
>
> Using winmode=None
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 57, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 44, in main
>     dll00 = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME, winmode=wmod)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\dll00.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py -w 0
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> PATH (original): c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4
> .8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts;C:\Us
> ers\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools;;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
>
> Using winmode=0
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 57, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 44, in main
>     dll00 = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME, winmode=wmod)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module './dll00.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py -p a
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> PATH (original): c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4
> .8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts;C:\Us
> ers\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools;;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
>
> Using winmode=None
> Using AddDllDirectory()
>
> Dll: <CDLL 'e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\dll00.dll', handle 7ffe6aaf0000 at 0x1f896d9ffd0>
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py -p a -w 0
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> PATH (original): c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4
> .8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts;C:\Us
> ers\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools;;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
>
> Using winmode=0
> Using AddDllDirectory()
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 57, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 44, in main
>     dll00 = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME, winmode=wmod)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module './dll00.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py -p p
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> PATH (original): c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4
> .8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts;C:\Us
> ers\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools;;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
>
> Using winmode=None
> Using %PATH%
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 57, in <module>
>     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\code00.py", line 44, in main
>     dll00 = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME, winmode=wmod)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
>     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059330863\dll00.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py -p p -w 0
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> PATH (original): c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4
> .8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\Tools\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Install\pc064\Docker\Docker\Version\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current\Win;e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts;C:\Us
> ers\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cfati\.dotnet\tools;;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
>
> Using winmode=0
> Using %PATH%
>
> Dll: <CDLL './dll00.dll', handle 7ffe6aaf0000 at 0x142a7a73cd0>
>
> Done.
> ```

Only 2 combinations (as expected) were successful (use *subdir00*):

- Pass it to *os.add_dll_directory* (with *winmode* *None*)
- Add it to *%PATH%* (with *winmode* *0*)

##### Conclusions

There are more ways of adding *dir*s where to search for (dependent) *.dll*s:

1. ***os.add_dll_directory***:

   - Default (and recommended) option (there are 3<sup>rd</sup>-party modules that load *.dll*s this way)
   - Consistent with the way *Python* loads extension module (*.pyd*) dependencies
2. ***%PATH%*** (and alter *winmode*):

   - Works with older (< *v3.8*) *Python* versions
   - Seems closer with *Nix* - where paths are typically added to *${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}* (*DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH*, *LIBPATH*, *SHLIB_PATH*, ...)
   - Can be customized by *winmode*'s value
3. **Change directory** to *.dll* location (more like a workaround):

   - Won't work if *.dll*s are in multiple directories (can't have multiple *CWD*s at the same time)

Related (more or less):

- [[SO]: Load a DLL with dependencies in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776284/4788546)
- [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)
- [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)

Comment: I've expanded to show what exactly changed in the search mechanism.

Comment: To remind myself every time I go here, this does not work on unix or macOS. add_dll_directory is only found on windows.

Comment: @Konchog: that's true, the question is tagged *Windows*, it's about *.dll*s, the *doc* also mentions it. Anyway modified the answer to be more explicit. For other *OS*es, it goes the "regular" way: e.g. setting *LD\LIBRARY\_PATH*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645968/where-does-ctypes-loadlibrary-search-for-libs-on-os-x

Comment: On MacOS, The following seem to have an effect in os.environment
'DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH'
'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'
'DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH'
'DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH'

Comment: Nope, only winmode 1 worked for me(even without using os.add_dll_directory. ), but it fails with segmentation error when accessing the function. winmode 2 compiles but does not help as it fails to recognize the function where I am setting some args. I am using cygwin on windows 11. Python is at 3.10

Answer (score 26):

A year late, but I've figured out what is going on and how to fix it. If you look at the code for [`ctypes.CDLL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL) on around [line 340](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L340), you can see that the docs are actually incorrect. The code defines the constructor as

```
def __init__(self, name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None,
             use_errno=False, use_last_error=False, winmode=None):
```

The docs, however, say `winmode=0`. If you look at [line 358](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L358), you can see that it matters quite a bit. When `winmode=None`, the search mode used by `_ctypes.LoadLibrary` in [line 374](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L374) (aliased as `_dlopen` in [line 110](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L110)) is set to `nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS` on [line 363](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L363). This search mode does not appear to respond to changes to [`os.environ['PATH']`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) or [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory).

However, if you bypass that setting by using `winmode=0` instead of `None`, the library appears to load fine. Zero is a valid mode for a full path (as would be `nt._LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH`). A full list of modes is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa, under the `dwFlags` parameter.

As [@CristiFati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/2988730) indicates, the behavior changed in Python 3.8. This happened because prior to that, the `winmode` parameter did not exist. Instead, `mode` was used directly, with a default value of `ctypes.DEFAULT_MODE`, which happens to correspond to a zero and work on all platforms.

Python bug report to resolve discrepancy: https://bugs.python.org/issue42114

Comment: Yes, I remember that I went through the *CTypes* code a year ago. You are right, the doc does not reflect what's in the code (hmm, I wonder how come I missed that). However, you're not correct about *os.add\_dll\_directory.* With `winmode=None` things work fine because of *LOAD\_LIBRARY\_SEARCH\_USER\_DIRS* which is sensitive to *AddDllDirectory*.

Comment: With `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS`, the current directory and `PATH` are ignored for the sake of security, but the default search path includes the application directory (of python.exe) and System32 directory, and any directory added via `os.add_dll_directory`. If all dependent DLLs are distributed in the same directory, then nothing special should be needed other than using a qualified path to ensure that it uses the flag `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR`. Otherwise, for a secure load, as used by default, you have to manually include every required directory via `os.add_dll_directory`.

Comment: @CristiFati. It didn't work on win 10. I would have expected the flags to work as you described. Perhaps there's something different in the security that Eryk is referring to.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I just created a small example (that I can add to my answer if you like): *Python* code that loads a *.dll* which depends on another *.dll* (located in a different *dir*). As expected, it doesn't work *OOTB*. In *Python 3.7* adding that *dir* to *%PATH%* fixes it, but not on *Python 3.8*. Adding that same *dir* with *os.add\_dll\_directory* **solves the problem in *Python 3.8***. I am on *Win 10*. Maybe on older *OS* versions it didn't work because the flag does not exist without installing *KB2533623*?

Comment: You have to analyze the dependent DLLs if you want a secure load. Try it first with `winmode=0`. Then in Process Explorer, switch the view in the bottom pane to show the full path of loaded DLLs. All directories except the application directory (of python.exe), the System32 directory, and the directory that contains the DLL that was directly loaded via `ctypes.CDLL` have to be added manually via `os.add_dll_directory` before calling `ctypes.CDLL`. If dependencies are in the DLL directory, make sure the path passed to CDLL is qualified in order to include its directory in the search.

Comment: @ErykSun: I was talking about *LOAD\_LIBRARY\_SEARCH\_USER\_DIRS*.

Comment: @ErykSun: I was trying to imagine a scenario that *os.add\_dll\_directory* wouldn't do the trick (as MadPhysicist suggests in the 3rd comment). Probably if running *Python 3.8* on an older *Win* version without that *KB*, the flag would not be present there (and most likely the functionality (search *AddDllDirectory* paths) associated with it would not work either).

Comment: @ErykSun. I think I see your point about dependency analysis. I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: @ErykSun. Thanks for the tip. I carefully added all the dependent folders and everything started working as expected.

Comment: Please change "does not appear to respond to changes to `os.environ['PATH']`, `sys.path` or `os.add_dll_directory`" to an accurate statement such as "does not include `os.environ['PATH']` and the current working directory". `sys.path` is for Python modules; there's no need to mention it here. Also, note that `mode` doesn't matter in Windows; it used to be passed to but not used by low-level `_ctypes.LoadLibrary`; hence the need for `winmode`. It would also be good to summarize some steps needed to support the secure DLL search path with the default `winmode=None` and `os.add_dll_directory`.

Comment: @ErykSun. I'll read through the comments you made, as well as some other stuff tonight and rewrite this answer.

Comment: @bomben. Comments are not a good place to ask a question that's clearly going to take a lot of detail to answer. Please ask a separate question with a [mcve]

Comment: @bomben. Possibly, but you are not providing nearly enough information in the comments, and please don't try

Comment: @MadPhysicist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937083/why-are-my-dlls-not-found-despite-me-importing-the-path-and-can-i-use-vlc-in-py

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice, thanks much for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

I partially agree with @MadPhysicist's answer, but I have Python 3.9, not 3.8, and with `winmode=0` error haven't disappeared. But with `winmode=1` everything is working!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74867788/4788546.

Answer (score 2):

OK so i fixed it, it was required that i changed the working directory to where the script was being executed before loading the dll from the same place.

```
os.chdir('path_to_working_dlls_directoy')
```

not entirely sure why this helped though.

Comment: Note that this is just a workaround. If there are multiple folders with *.dll*s, it won't work. Try the suggestion from my answer. -1.

Answer (score -2):

Just "Visual C++ Redistributable Package per Visual Studio 2013". The problem will be solved.

Comment: This is incorrect. -1.

Answer (score -3):

You can specify the path to the library

```
import snap7
import struct
from snap7.common import Snap7Library
from snap7.util import *

# If you are using a different location for the library
Snap7Library(lib_location='C:/snap7/snap7.dll')
load_library() #Testing library is correctly <WinDLL 'C:\snap7\snap7.dll', handle 7ff9d5d90000 at 0x1a5a0417640>

plc = snap7.client.Client()
plc.connect("10.112.115.10",0,1)
```