# OpenCV Python with CUDA on Windows: DLL Load Failed

Tags: python, windows, opencv, 64-bit

I am trying to get OpenCV python bindings to work with CUDA, but when I run

```
import cv2
```

I get the following error:

```
OpenCV loader: os.name="nt"  platform.system()="Windows"
OpenCV loader: loading config: C:\opencv\build\python_loader\cv2\config.py
OpenCV loader: loading config: C:\opencv\build\python_loader\cv2\config-3.8.py
OpenCV loader: PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS=['C:/opencv/build/lib/python3/Release']
OpenCV loader: BINARIES_PATHS=['C:/opencv/build/bin/Release']
OpenCV loader: PATH=C:/opencv/build/bin/Release;C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\Perl64\c\bin;C:\Perl64\perl\site\bin;C:\Perl64\perl\bin;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.5.0\;C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc16\bin\;C:\Users\md249\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
OpenCV loader: replacing cv2 module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\opencv\build\python_loader\cv2\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\opencv\build\python_loader\cv2\__init__.py", line 86, in bootstrap
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have the following environment variables set:

```
OPENCV_DIR: C:\opencv\build\
PATH: $PATH;C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc16\bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin
```

It seems that OpenCV builds binaries to multiple different directories for reasons I do not understand, so I am unsure where to point PATH and OPENCV_DIR.

Running Dependency Walker against `cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` does not indicate any missing dependencies from OpenCV or CUDA.

Does the .pyd dynamically load any other dependencies that Dependency Walker might not catch? 
C++ applications load OpenCV just fine so I imagine the problem has something to do with where the .pyd extension is looking for dependencies.

Hopefully I have included all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error message when importing `cv2`, but I compiled *OpenCV* from source including the extra modules from *opencv_contrib*, because I wanted a `Win64` build including `cuda*` and `python3` modules.

### Workaround

Even after investing an extended amount of time I cannot offer a satisfying solution. But my functioning workaround is to use *dumpbin* or *Dependency walker* to find all the `cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` dependencies recursively and provide all of them including `cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` from the same flat directory, which you add to `PYTHONPATH`.

In my case this meant the following manual steps after compiling *OpenCV* from source:

- Make a directory like `C:\opencv-py39`.
- Copy `cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` to `C:\opencv-py39`.
- Copy all OpenCV shared libs (`${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}\*.dll` e.g. `opencv_world455.dll`) to `C:\opencv-py39`.
- Copy all CUDA-relevant shared libs (`%CUDA_PATH%\bin\*.dll`) to `C:\opencv-py39`.
- Copy all *Intel TBB* shared libs (`%ONEAPI_ROOT%\tbb\latest\redist\intel64\vc14\*.dll`) to `C:\opencv-py39`.
- Set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH=C:\opencv-py39`.

Depending on the build options you choose this list might be inconclusive.

### More details

This **workaround** bypasses the problems that I experience not having the dependencies of my `cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` loaded from their specific installation directories even if environment variables are set properly and C++ example progams build and execute as expected. I guess this is specific to the shared library loader of *CPython*. I have found [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330863/cant-import-dll-module-in-python#64472088) that this problem might have been introduced in Python 3.8.

Having a closer look using [SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) *procmon* utility reveals, that the python interpreter stops using the right module name while probing all the configured DLL search directories. I.e. it starts looking for `opencv_world455.dll` in the current working directory, then in the Python directory etc. but when it starts to look into the PATH's directories it uses a faulty module name like `<stdin>` or similar corrupted names. Maybe I should submit a bug report to CPython...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@salchint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10756290/salchint) workaround:

I got the same `ImportError` problem with my installation and solved it thanks to an Anaconda install I had on the side.

It turns out that all the missing DLLs could be found in `.../Anaconda3/Library/bin`. So including the folder to your script with:

```py
import os
os.add_dll_directory('path_to_Anaconda/Anaconda3/Library/bin')
```

Solved the error for me.
Note that this folder *is* in my Path and should be discoverable but Python has (or had?) [some problems](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80266) doing it.

A cleaner solution (but still a workaround) is then to add this command to the `__init__.py` file of the `cv2` module in `YOUR_PYTHON_PATH/Lib/site-packages`

I wrote about it in more detail [here](https://github.com/chrismeunier/OpenCV-CUDA-installation/blob/main/README.md#check-install-and-troubleshooting).

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because you didnt installed OpenCV, you donwloaded it, if you don't want to spend time configuring extra path to make sure python finds the right opencv package you just need to install it using 'pip':

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

It will probably solve you problem, and the C++ software can still use the downloaded version without conflict.

[Install Reference](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

Comment: your assessment is not correct, i have the same issue as the OP and i compiled the library configuring all paths correctly. And your recommendation about installing opencv-contrib-python is also wrong as OP clearly wants OpenCV with CUDA, when you directly install opencv-contrib-python like you are suggesting, it does not support CUDA.