# Python pupil_Apriltags : Problem with DLL path "Could not find module"

Tags: python, opencv, dll, apriltags

Hello I have a problem with [pupil_apriltags](https://github.com/pupil-labs/apriltags) in python.
I have been searching for more than 1 week and tried multiple solutions but none of them worked.

My problem is not with the import of the librairy but when I try to create the **detector**. There is a reference to a xxxx.dll file (I think) which does not work.

##### My code

Very simple

```
from pupil_apriltags import Detector
import cv2
import numpy as np


at_detector = Detector(families='tag36h11',
                       nthreads=1,
                       quad_decimate=1.0,
                       quad_sigma=0.0,
                       refine_edges=1,
                       decode_sharpening=0.25,
                       debug=0)
```

##### My error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                  
File "detection_apriltags.py", line 6, in <module>                                                                        
at_detector = Detector()                                                                                              
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pupil_apriltags\bindings.py", line 285, in __init__
self.libc = ctypes.CDLL(str(hit))                                                                                     
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__                                       
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)                                                                            
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Utilisateur\anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\pupil_apriltags\lib\apriltag.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path 
with constructor syntax.
```

##### My configuration

- Python 3.8.5
- Windows 10

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This library does not seem to be widely used so it may be worth to ask about this problem on the library GitHub [Issues](https://github.com/pupil-labs/apriltags/issues) page as well. If you get a solution there don't forget to post it here as an answer. Good luck!

Comment: I had the same problem, apparently the *.dll* search mechanism changed in python 3.**8** You can see more details of how to fix it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330863/cant-import-dll-module-in-python). I didn't have any requirement to use python 3.8 so I used [python 3.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3614/) instead, and the library worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i didn't find the solution with pupils-Apriltags (on Windows) but i discorver [Aruco](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/12/21/detecting-aruco-markers-with-opencv-and-python/) which is derectly in Opencv ( with the package : opencv-contrib-python, at this day).

```
arucoDict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_50) 
arucoParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
(corners, ids, rejected) = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image, arucoDict,parameters=arucoParams)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from Manuel Valenzuela I was able to solve the problem and I made a PR to the pupil-apriltags repo; after this the issue should no longer be a problem.

https://github.com/pupil-labs/apriltags/pull/48

As Manuel says, this is an issue in Python 3.8 and up with the DLL search.  The one who really figured it out was @Mad Physicist though:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472088/1832942