# How to prepare environment for call python code in C code?

Tags: python, c, cpython

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

[embedding python in C](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html)

I tried the example given by the official tutorial.
it worked on condition that the python path is set in environment path variables. What if the python environment is embeded in the C project, how can I assign the python path dynamically within the code. I've tried `_putenv` method before the Python Virtual Machine is initiated, but in vain. As is instructed in the Python/C Api Doc, some function can be called before the initialization like `Py_SetPath` or `Py_SetPythonHome`[in doc](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#before-python-initialization), it cast an error like "pythonxx.dll"  cannot be found. I don't know how to do then?

```
gcc 9.2.0 mingw 32bit
windows10
python3.8.10 32bit
```

Comment: What are the expected and actual results? What's the *OS* and build commands? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Comment `Py_SetProgramName(program);`.

Comment: @CristiFati  on Windows,```gcc -o test.exe test.c -Wall -lpython38 -L pythonpath\libs -I pythonpath\include```. Actually the output ```test.exe``` would work on condition that I've set system environment path for the embeded python directory or just put the executable right in the python directory . What I want to do is that whether I can set the  python environment path in the ```test.c```. And I've tried to set it with Windows api ```_putenv```, but it seems to be in vain. I don't know how.

Comment: @CristiFati is your python env is Conda env which has already been add to the system path list? do you encounter "pythonxx.dll" not found error

Comment: It works, both in  *VEnv* and outside it (didn't try it in *Conda*). I also added `printf("Exe: %S\nPath: %S\nExecPrefix: %S\n", Py_GetProgramFullPath(), Py_GetPath(), Py_GetExecPrefix());` and it prints values.

Comment: @CristiFati well, it can be kind of hard to tell the difference between your dealing with this project with mine in detail

Comment: The question still lacks details like the toolchain used, and the *Python* version attempted (native or part of that toolchain). But it's most likely a duplicate of [\[SO\]: Why does adding multiprocessing prevent python from finding my compiled c program? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75035737/4788546) (or [\[SO\]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546)
). Following the guidelines there you should get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @CristiFati thanks.  it's just the python 3.8.10 / 32bit. python38.dll cannot be found.