# import "nt" could not be resolved

Tags: python, openai-gym

While trying to load the following Openai-gym environment:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('Breakout-v4', render_mode='human')
```

I'm encountering this error: `FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\...\atari_py\ale_interface\ale_c.dll'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

I am in windows, using python 3.8.0

### What I have tried:

- Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/20143298), nothing changed.
- When trying to follow [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472088/20143298), looking into `__init__.py`, I have encountered the problem: `import "nt" could not be resolved`
- Trying to replace `__init__.py` file with [this file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py), as they were not the same. The same problem still occurs.

I suspect that this is the root cause of the problem.

Am I right? How can it be solved?

Edit: the problem was rooted in gym version. I have updated the version and solved the issue.

Comment: Which OS are you on? How have you installed `gym`? What is the full traceback to the error?

Comment: As an aside, it's pretty much a terrible idea to replace library files such as `ctypes/__init__.py` with other versions.

Comment: @AKX It's quite clearly Windows from the error message. The installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1726).

Comment: I.e. the issue probably has nothing to do with ctypes being broken, but atari-py being partially? installed.

Comment: @AKX You were right.  it wasn't a problem with ctypes. it was a problem with the version of gym, who was surprisingly at 0.15.7 (probobaly because of baselines version), I have updated the version and got the solution.