# Python can't locate .so shared library with ctypes.CDLL - Windows

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am trying to run a C function in Python. I followed examples online, and compiled the C source file into a .so shared library, and tried to pass it into the ctypes CDLL() initializer function.

```
import ctypes
cFile = ctypes.CDLL("libchess.so")
```

At this point python crashes with the message:

`Could not find module 'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\libchess.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax`.

libchess.so is in the same directory as this Python file, so I don't see why there would be an issue finding it.

I read some stuff about how shared libraries might be hidden from later versions of python, but the suggested solutions I tried did not work. Most solutions were also referring to fixes involving linux system environment variables, but I'm on Windows.

**Things I've tried that have not worked:**

- changing "libchess.so" to "./libchess.so" or the full path
- using cdll.LoadLibrary() instead of CDLL() (apparently both do the same thing)
- adding the parent directory to system PATH variable
- putting `os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())` in the code before trying to load the file

Any more suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) the ***Conclusions***  section at the end. Most likely your *.dll* (*.so*) has dependencies that can't be loaded, because they are not found. Please add more details on how you build your *.dll*. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

Detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472088/16044321

The issue is specific to how Python performs a DLL/SO search on Windows. While the ctypes docs do not specify this, the CDLL() function requires the optional argument `winmode=0` to work correctly on Windows when loading a .dll or .so. This issue is also specific to Python versions greater than 3.8.

Thus, simply changing the 2nd line to `cFile = ctypes.CDLL("libchess.so", winmode=0)` works as expected.